# Array formula in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying the following code to find the location of several values:

```
Dim destino as String
Dim origen as String
destino="A"
origen="B"
Dim fila as Integer
fila = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(1, (Range("F:F") = origen) * (Range("G:G") = destino), 0)
```

But it doesn't work. Does anybody know why?

Comment: What doesn't work? What error do you get?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're expecting to return.  Can you make it work as a worksheet formula?  If yes then it would be useful add that formula to the question: likely you could use something based on `Worksheet.Evaluate` ...

Comment: Also, if you're running it literally as you have it, there is no `origen` or `destino`...so it doesn't have anything to compare the ranges to.

Comment: I get a Type Missmatch error. No, it's not literal, there is a value for origen and destino. It works as a Worksheet fromula:

Comment: {=MATCH(1, (F:F= origen) * (G:G = destino), 0)}

Comment: So you only want the position od the first match ?  Try `fila = WorkSheets("sheetNameHere").Evaluate("=MATCH(1, (F:F= origen) * (G:G = destino), 0)")`  You shouldn't need to include the "{}"

Comment: Yes, the position of the first match that fulfills those two conditions (there could be more).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim f As Integer
    Dim destino as String
    Dim origen as String

    destino = "B"
    origen = "R"

    f = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("=MATCH(1,(C:C=""" & destino & """) * (D:D=""" & origen & """),0)")
    Debug.Print f '>> 6

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect, but I need "B" and "R" to be vba variables, like origen and destino. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I have one more question regarding this issue. If destino or origen were numbers (integers), how should the code be?

Comment: ActiveSheet.Evaluate("=MATCH(1,(C:C=" & destino & ") * (D:D=" & origen & "),0)")